# Create a popup window on iPAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, popupwindow

How can I create a popup window like in this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUQwc.jpg]

I can create UIView and show it with a toolbar and tableview but I don't know how can I show a black overlay and is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just an [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the [`modalPresentationStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW67) property set [`UIModalPresentationPageSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalPresentationStyle) or [`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalPresentationStyle)

Answer (score 0):

I give you simple trick:

Create one custom `UIView` (dimView) which frame is similar to `window.bounds` and `BackGroundColor` is **black** and `alpha = 0.5f`;

Add another custom `UIView` with on `UITableView` which style is `grouped` and also you need to add UINavigationBar with **done** `UIBarButtonItem`
And add your custom controls on `UITableView`'s cell.